# Confusion routing Ruby requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am following this routing tutorial for Ruby on Rails:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

It says that when I need to create a new url, I should make a route for it.  So I did that. 
I would like to have a url like this www.domain.com/fomats/formats.html.rb so I did something like this in the routes.rb file:

```
  resources :formats
  get "formats/index" #display all formats
```

Is that correct?  For my index route, I also have something like this in my route.rb file: root :to => "home#index" - should I have something like this in the formats route?

Also, how do I create the actual controller?  Do I make it by hand, or does rails somehow create the stub of it for me?

Right now I get this error:

```
missing :action
```

Does that mean I am missing the controller or something else?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: What is formats? is it something that can be a resource?

Comment: Another confusion: Rails triggers requests, not Ruby :)

Comment: @Sam formats in the application I am building is FileFormats so it is something that can be a resource, yes. It is an entity.

Comment: You should read [Michael Hartl's tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/). Buy the book (much easier) or read it online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, you should probably continue studying with other books or resources. These fundamental questions you are asking may become more clear the more you read.

Here are some quickfire hints that hopefully help you.

### ---

When you declare this in the routes.rb file:

```
resources :formats
```

You automatically get the following declaration for free, so you don't have to re-declare it:

```
get "formats/index" # Don't add this to routes.rb
```

### ---

URL's in rails look like this:

```
www.domain.com/formats
```

That URL would map to "formats#index"

### ---

To see what explicit routes have been generated, run this in your rails root directory:

```
rake routes
```

### ---

To create a controller:

```
rails g controller formats
```

Comment: Thank you that helped.  And yeah the questions are basic, but by the nature of my current project, I am in a bit of a time rush, so I am just glad I can come to this site for quick help and explanations.